# Woocommerce - display different text on product page if product has tag "xyz"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display certain text or html under the price of my woocommerce shop according to tag which the product uses.

For example, if my product "T-SHIRT" has product tag "Clothes", display text "This product is tagged as CLOTHES" under the price, or under the description or whereelse on product page

And then, if My product "UNDERWEAR" has product tag "Calvin Klein", display text "This product is made by Calvin Klein" ...

Thanks for any kind of help :-).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't test this but I think this should put you in the right direction:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_text', 10, 2 );

function custom_price_text( $price, $object ) {

    $terms = get_the_terms( $object->post->ID 'product_tag' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        if ( $term->name == 'Clothes' ) {
            $text = 'This product is tagged as CLOTHES';
        } elseif ( $term->name == 'Calvin Klein' ) {
            $text = 'This product is made by Calvin Klein';
        }

    }

    return $price . $text;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd want to do something like this: `function custom_price_text( $price, $object ) {
        $prod_id = get_the_ID();
        $terms = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'product_tag' );
`
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check if a product has a certain tag attached to it is using the [has_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) function,
the taxonomy to look in is `product_tag`;

here's an example referring to OP scenario:

```
$isTshirt = has_term('t-shirt', 'product_tag');
```